# Incrementing variable per minute using Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am doing a program in VB.NET (Visual Basic 2008) wherein I need variable `X` to be incremented by `1` per minute, with the default value of `0`. So far, I have made a timer that counts the passing minutes and seconds from where the form is loaded. And from there, I am kinda stuck.

This is the code I got:

```
Dim X as Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    X = 0
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Function ConvertFunction(ByVal Counter As Integer) As String
    Dim Mins, Secs As Integer
    Secs = Counter Mod 60
    Mins = Counter \ 60
    Return Mins.ToString("00") & ":" & Secs.ToString("00")
End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static Counter As Integer
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Label1.Text = ConvertFunction(Counter)
End Sub
```

Help, anyone? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I forgot to include one detail, which I just realized that could be confusing.

The default value is `0` at the initial load of the program, but since it is also referenced to a database, after a while it might be `10` or something so the next time the program is loaded, its starting point would be from `10`.

Sorry about that. :/

Comment: What is the problem? Which part isn't working?'

Comment: The code I included is perfectly working. I'm just stuck at the part where I need to reference the timer to the variable X. It needs to increment per minute.

Comment: Cant you just add `X = Mins` after `Mins = Counter \ 60`?

Comment: @N55PEC, I edited my original post, I didn't realize it was confusing. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have everything you need in the code you posted, but your timer is firing every second (1000ms). Just change this to fire every minute and that should be enough:

```
Dim X as Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    X = 0 'or any other value from the database
    Timer1.Interval = 60000 'fires every minute
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    X += 1 ' increment the X after each minute passes
End Sub
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It doesn't state that as far as I can see

Comment: If you see OP's `Timer1_Tick` you'll come to know.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - he states that he wants to update the value every minute. The code posted fires the timer every second (I assume this is either in error or in any case not required). We can only go off the requirements specified not second guessing from the code posted what the intention is.